# Populate a private static class map<string,Base*> with pointers to dynamically allocated Derived classes

Tags: c++, class, templates

I have a private static member variable of a class Central, with type map. I want to populate this map with " Base* " pointers, which point to instances of classes deriving from " Base ". These instances of the derived classes must be stored in dynamic memory. There is a bit of template fun involved also. I did try a method to populate the map, but it gave me a compilation error (which will be stated later).

Here is a code snippet for clarity:

```
#include <all_necesary_std_headers>

class Base
{
    /* guts */
};

template<class CType>
class Derived: public Base
{
    /* innards */
};

class Central
{
    /* partial entrails */
private:
    // the static map I was referring to
    static std::map<string, Base*> base_map;
};

// Initializing the static map here
std::map<string, Base*> Central::base_map;

class Test1
{
    /* viscera */
};

// Compilation error here, on next line of code.
Central::base_map["Test1"] = dynamic_cast<Base*>( new Derived<Test1>);

class Test2
{
    /* bowels */
};

// Compilation error here, on next line of code.
Central::base_map["Test2"] = dynamic_cast<Base*>( new Derived<Test2>);
```

**This is the Compilation error that I get:**
*error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '=' token;*

I already have a destructor that frees the memory allocated by the map, so no need to remind me. I want to use the class " Central " in main(). This class structure will be used to dynamically create new instances of classes, from class names stored in files.

Hope it is clear, please say if anything isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assignment statements can only go in functions, not at namespace scope.

In C++11, you can initialise the map in its declaration:

```
std::map<string, Base*> Central::base_map = {
    {"Test1", new Derived<Test1>},
    {"Test2", new Derived<Test2>}
};
```

If you're stuck in the past, then you'll need to use a function to populate the map; perhaps something like:

```
std::map<string, Base*> make_base_map() {
    std::map<string, Base*> map;
    map["Test1"] = new Derived<Test1>;
    map["Test2"] = new Derived<Test2>;
    return map;
}

std::map<string, Base*> Central::base_map = make_base_map();
```

Also, note that you can't use `dynamic_cast` unless these types are polymorphic (i.e. `Base` has at least one virtual function). You can convert `Derived<T>*` to `Base*` without a cast, as I've done in my examples; but if you need to convert back with `dynamic_cast` then you'll need to make sure they are polymorphic.

UPDATE: If you want to be able to register each class separately by adding code only to that class's implementation files, then you'll need to declare a static object that registers the class in its constructor. Now we run into the initialisation order fiasco: if static objects are initialised in different translation units then the initialisation order is unspecified, so you can't safely access one from the constructor of the other.

We can fix this by making the map a local static variable, initialised the first time it's accessed:

```
static std::map<string, Base*> & base_map() {
    static std::map<string, Base*> map;
    return map;
}
```

Now we can define the class to register the classes:

```
template <typename T>
struct BaseMapEntry {
    explicit BaseMapEntry(string name) {
        base_map()[name] = new Derived<T>;
    }
};
```

And use it for each class:

```
// header file
class Test1
{
    static BaseMapEntry<Test1> entry;
    /* gubbins */
};

// source file
BaseMapEntry<Test1> Test1::entry("Test1");
```

(Alternatively, you could make it a static namespace-scope object in the source file, rather than a static member; the choice is largely aesthetic. Unfortunately, whatever you do will have to be defined in the source file due to the One Definition Rule.)

Comment: Base has virtual functions. I should have mentioned it. Base acts as a handle to the templated derived classes. I made it virtual, because I wont know what derived type I get during run-time, as I load the class names from the file.

Comment: @mcvz: OK. But you still don't need `dynamic_cast` for these conversions, and using it might cause unnecessary confusion.

Comment: The whole point of doing it this way, is so that I can add more and more Derived<T> classes to the static map, as I write new classes in my project.

Comment: @mcrz  `dynamic_cast` when you take the instances out.  Do not `dynamic_cast` when you put them in.

Comment: @mcvz: Indeed, I understand why you're storing `Base*`. I'm just saying that converting `Derived<T>*` to `Base*` doesn't need a cast, and that using an unnecessary cast might cause confusion.

Comment: I would prefer to avoid using a function to populate the static map. I would prefer adding a new <string, Base*> pair in the header file where I declare my class. Is there perhaps a way to define a templated static method in Central that adds a single element into the static map?

Comment: @mcvz: OK, that's possible but a bit fiddly due to the infamous static initialisation fiasco. I'll see if I can update the answer with a solution.

Comment: @MikeSeymour. Worked like a charm. Thanks. The code blew my mind for a while. Haha.

Answer (score 0):

use this line to add a new value to the map (from member-functions or ctor):

```
Central::base_map["Test1"] = new Derived<Test1>();
```

if you want to fill it with some values on initialize, use `boost::assign` or C++11:

```
std::map<string, Base*> Central::base_map = { 
  {"Test1", new Derived<Test1>()}, 
  {"Test2", new Derived<Test2>()} 
};
```

Comment: Just to test, I'm going to make the static map a public member, and try again.

Comment: Still get a compilation error with the static map as a public member.